# Facebook Permissions - how to add extended permissions on a per-user basis after sign in

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-3.2, facebook-javascript-sdk, koala-gem

I have a rails app that uses Facebook login with the very basic permissions: `email,user_photos,user_birthday`. It appears that asking users for extended permissions like `publish_stream` really drops the sign-up rate to my app (and it makes sense - I wouldn't trust anyone with permission to publish to my FB feed without getting to know the service).

The app enables users to share content on their walls, but first I need to add the `publish_stream` permission to users who actively seek it out.

What's a good way to approach this? Is it possible to do this at all? thanks.

Comment: When the user wants to post something via your app – just ask them for the permission than and there …?

Comment: You might want to look at: http://pulkitgoyal.in/2013/01/09/requesting-extended-permissions-facebook-sdk-android/

Answer (score 2):

You can append the permission to the url and have that url available for those who actively seek out the ability to share on your app:

```
www.blah.com/users/auth/facebook?scope=publish_actions,email
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Devise with Omniauth, just add a `scope` to the path helper:

`user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook, scope: 'email,publish_actions')`

This is basically the other answer, but expressed in a more Railsy way.